# I got message when want ask in askubuntu

Tags: support

I'am get this message when clicked "Ask Question" on AskUbuntu

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

What should i do if i want ask a question. Please anyone help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the link that you didn't read:

> ### How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.

**Stack Exchange cannot lift question bans by request.**

> The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out". **Begin by fixing your existing posts**; *do not* just post the same question again. All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors, too, so put effort into writing with proper grammar and spelling, formatting your post so it can be read easily, and providing as much detail as possible about your problem and what you have already tried. Reading your question out loud to yourself can help you understand what it sounds like to others.

You have 6 questions. Go improve them.

Comment: You might want to add a bit about requesting deleted answers/questions to be undeleted if need be, maybe that should even be put in the help page?

Comment: Just a distraction in most cases, @Seth. If your publicly-visible stuff all looks *awesome* and you're still having problems, *then* look into deleted stuff.